# Decoding Hash from JSON-String in Perl

Tags: json, perl, hash

Why does this not work?

```
my $myHashEncoded = encode_json \%myHash;
my %myHashDecoded = decode_json($myHashEncoded);
```

I get the error:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at ...
```

So I changed it to:

```
my $myHashEncoded = encode_json \%myHash;
my $myHashDecoded = decode_json($enableInputEncoded);
```

But then obviously `%myHash` is not the same as `$myHashDecoded`.

How do I restore a proper hash from the JSON string?

Comment: Which module are you getting `encode_json` and `decode_json` from?

Comment: I included use JSON;

Comment: You can dereference hash, `my %myHashDecoded = %{ decode_json($enableInputEncoded) };`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are using JSON.pm, [the documentation says](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#decode_json):

> The opposite of encode_json: expects an UTF-8 (binary) string and tries to parse that as an UTF-8 encoded JSON text, returning the resulting **reference**.

So you are getting back what you put in. You're putting in a hashref and you're getting a hashref back.

If you want a regular hash, then you just dereference it as you would any other hashref:

```
my $myHashRefDecoded = decode_json($myHashEncoded);
my %myHashDecoded = %$myHashRefDecoded;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick relpy. And sorry for my ignorance regarding the documentation.

Comment: This really helped me grok some aspects of Perl that (as a newcomer) didn't make a lot of sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are encoding a *reference* to a hash (`encode_json \%myHash`), which is correct. So when you decode your JSON string you are receiving a reference to a hash. Prepend a `%` sigil to a hash reference to dereference it.

```
$myHashReferenceDecoded = decode_json($myHashReferenceEncoded);
%myHashDecoded = %$myHashReferenceDecoded;
```

Answer (score 2):

On the following line, you do two things: you create a reference to the hash (`\`), and you encode the result (`encode_json`):

```
my $myHashEncoded = encode_json(\%myHash);
```

One the following line, you decode the JSON (`decode_json`), but you don't "undo" the reference.

```
my %myHashDecoded = decode_json($myHashEncoded);
```

The real inverse operation would involve a hash derereference.

```
my %myHashDecoded = %{ decode_json($myHashEncoded) };
```

But that needlessly makes a (shallow) copy of the hash. Maybe you should just work with the reference instead.

```
my $myHashDecoded = decode_json($myHashEncoded);
```

By the way, the reason a reference is used is that it's impossible to pass a hash to a sub or to return a hash from a sub. Only list of scalar can be passed and returned.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON API is consistent. If you use a reference to a hash when encoding, you also get a hash reference when decoding.
So if you want to store the result in a pure hash variable, you have to dereference the result of `decode_json` with `%{ ... }`.

Solution:

```
my $myHashEncoded = encode_json \%myHash;
my %myHashDecoded = %{ decode_json($myHashEncoded) };
```

Note that dereferencing a hash is a costly operation. You should really consider if using directly the reference is not enough in your code.