# How do I decipher an array of hashes?

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I totally got this question wrong. Am using the method from TMDB:

```
 my @results = $search->find(id     => 'tt0114694', source => 'imdb_id');
```

I thought the output was in JSON format, so that's what confused me, which kept me running in circles because I was looking at it all wrong.

Didn't realize the data below, from Dumper, was the actual hashes the I had to go through.

This is where I am running into a wall, So the data below is a hash with five keys.  The fifth key, the I want, contains another array. It is that array I cannot read into. I try dereferencing that into a hash, and that is where I fail.

The code I am trying is:

```
foreach my $narray (@results){
    print $narray->{"movie_results"};
    my @newarray = $narray->{"movie_results"};

    foreach my $otherarray (@newarray){
        my %innerhash = $otherarray;
        print %innerhash;
        print "\n";
    }
  }
```

It will print out an array, but I am unable to read the hash in that array.

*p.s. I had to format this output as code, or else it came out with no line breaks.*

```
   $VAR1 = {
              'tv_season_results' => [],
              'tv_results' => [],
              'person_results' => [],
              'tv_episode_results' => [],
              'movie_results' => [
                                   {
                                     'adult' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
                                     'vote_average' => '6.8',
                                     'original_title' => 'Tommy Boy',
                                     'vote_count' => 635,
                                     'id' => 11381,
                                     'release_date' => '1995-03-31',
                                     'overview' => 'Party animal Tommy Callahan is a few cans short of a six-pack. But when the family business starts tanking, it\'s up to Tommy and number-cruncher Richard Hayden to save the day.',
                                     'genre_ids' => [
                                                      35
                                                    ],
                                     'title' => 'Tommy Boy',
                                     'video' => $VAR1->{'movie_results'}[0]{'adult'},
                                     'poster_path' => '/g32WbO9nbY5ydpux5hIoiJkLEQi.jpg',
                                     'original_language' => 'en',
                                     'backdrop_path' => '/bZ4diYf7oyDVaRYeWG42Oify2mB.jpg',
                                     'popularity' => '13.945'
                                   }
                                 ]
            };
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interst https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759097/decoding-hash-from-json-string-in-perl

Comment: You asked "How can I decode a JSON into a readable hash in Perl?", but there's no JSON anywhere in your question. In fact, you already have a hash, and there's nothing stopping you from reading it So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @ikegami That was my first thought, except the return for that method is  an array , not a scalar which could be a reference to hash.

Comment: I have idea what you're talking about. I asked what's your question?

Comment: Well the method returns an array, so that would be an array of hashes.I'll go back to see that I am looping through them properly

Comment: Actually, the `find` method returns a single item. It just has a poor example that shows that being assigned to an array, and no useful docs that actually tell you what it means to do.

Comment: @briandfoy Yes it does return just one, but depending on what I am searching for, it could return more.

Comment: It returns the decoded JSON, and you are only going to get one thing back. That one thing might be a JSON array, but that's one thing. Note the actual code I dug up for my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with reference, use the same syntax as if you weren't, but replace the name of the variable with a block that returns the reference.

```
%NAME      -> %{ $ref }           Or just %$ref
$NAME{...} -> ${ $ref }{...}      Although $ref->{...} easier to read.

@NAME      -> @{ $ref }           Or just @$ref
$NAME[...] -> ${ $ref }[...]      Although $ref->[...] easier to read.
```

Let's give `$VAR` a better name,

```perl
my $response = $VAR1;
```

This means you want

```perl
my $results = $response->{movie_results};
for my $result (@$results) {
   for my $key (keys(%$result)) {
      say "$key: $result->{$key}";
   }
}
```

See

- [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut)
- [Perl Dereferencing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46507722/589924)

Comment: Yes this worked, and thank you. Now it's up to me to figure out to how to deference the other arrays inside there, but I should be able to take it from here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that you thought you'd get JSON output, but got something else. The module made a web request for you, received the JSON response, and translated that to a Perl data structure. That Perl version of the JSON is what you see in the dump.

A JSON object turns into a Perl hash, so that's what you see in the top level of the data structure. That's the single thing `find` returns (more on that in a moment):

Here's what you have, removing the outer `foreach` loop:

```
my @newarray = $narray->{"movie_results"};

foreach my $otherarray (@newarray){
    my %innerhash = $otherarray;
    print %innerhash;
    print "\n";
}
```

The value in `$narray->{"movie_results"}` is an array reference. All references are scalars, and those scalars point to some data structure. When you assign that scalar to an array, you just end up with a one element array that's the same reference. Instead, you can

```
my $movie_results = $narray->{"movie_results"};
```

You then dereference that reference to treat it as an array:

```
foreach my $result ( @$movie_results ){ ... }
```

Or, the v5.24 [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) way that I find slightly more pleasing since it reads better, especially when you skip the intermediate variable:

```
foreach my $result ( $movie_results->@* ){ ... }

foreach my $result ( $narray->{"movie_results"}->@* ){ ... }
```

That thing in `$result` is another hash reference.

References and data structures are about half of the content of [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com), but there is also [the Perl data structures cookbook (perldsc)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc).

### Improving your question a bit

You can help us a lot by showing us a complete, working demonstration of your problem. Here's what I cobbled together:

```
use v5.10;

use TMDB;
use Data::Dumper;

my $tmdb = TMDB->new( apikey => $ENV{TMDB_API_KEY} );
my @results = $tmdb->search->find(
    id     => 'tt0114694',
    source => 'imdb_id'
    );

say Dumper( \@results );
```

There was a question about the results of `find`. The documentation example shows it returning a list (well, the result being assigned to a named array, which implies that), but there's not actual documentation for `find`. It returns the decoded JSON from the response. Assigning it to a scalar (which will be a reference) works just fine too:

```
my $result = $tmdb->search->find(
    id     => 'tt0114694',
    source => 'imdb_id'
    );

say Dumper( $results );
```

The return value comes from `TMDB::Sesssion::talk()`, which is just this (or the empty list):

```
return $self->json->decode(
    Encode::decode( 'utf-8-strict', $response->{content} ) );
```

That's not a big deal. That just means you don't need the outer `foreach`. That's not on you because the example in the docs tells you to do exactly what you did.

### Now a better program

Putting all that together, here's a simple program pared down to just what you need:

```
use v5.10; 
use TMDB;

my $tmdb = TMDB->new( apikey => $ENV{TMDB_API_KEY} );
my $result = $tmdb->search->find(
    id     => 'tt0114694',
    source => 'imdb_id'
    );

foreach my $item ( $result->{movie_results}->@* ) {
    say "Title: $item->{title}";
    }
```

### Ref aliasing

There's an experimental feature called [ref aliasing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/08/create-named-variable-aliases-with-ref-aliasing/) that lets you assign a reference to a reference of a named variable. It's an alias, so you can access and change the same data, just with a named variable. Something this is handy when you don't like

```
use v5.10;

use TMDB;
use experimental qw(refaliasing);

my $tmdb = TMDB->new( apikey => $ENV{TMDB_API_KEY} );

# response is a hash ref, so ref alias to a named hash
\my %result = $tmdb->search->find(
    id     => 'tt0114694',
    source => 'imdb_id'
    );

# the part you want is an array ref, so alias that
\my @movie_results = $result{movie_results};

# each item in the array is a hash ref, so alias those too
foreach \my %item ( @movie_results ) {
    say "Title: $item{title}";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`%newhash{$newkey}` should be `$newhash{$newkey}`.

Comment: I did that, and got the same output, but each line ended with ARRAY(xxxxxxxxx)

Comment: @LuisC329, What's your point? The value is an array reference, so that's perfectly legit.

Comment: @ikegami I'm trying to place the JSON string into a hash, and I just seem to be caught in a redundant loop.

Comment: What JSON string? You haven't shown any JSON.

Comment: @ikegami I've obviously misread my situation. Have worked with hashes before, but only those I've made and passed and dereferenced.  Never got one from a method before in this format, so I thought It was a JSON.

Comment: @ikegami So now that I realize I am not dealing with a JSON, but a hash directly, I have gotten much further.  But that fifth key, movie_results, who's value is an array (which I believe contains hashes, that's where I keep running in circles.