# Perl JSON equivalent to JS JSON?

Tags: json, perl

So I am attempting to use a JSON array that looks like this:

```
$object = {
"location":["test1","test2","test3"], 
"quantity":[5, 10, 15] , 
"userstamp":["DudeGuy","Pope Francis","Hamburglar"]
}
```

JS JSON lets me directly access those values by assigning that to an $object, and then I can use `$object.location[1]`, and it should give me `test2`.

I'm not a Perl expert here, and I'm sort of unfamiliar if the JSON module can even do this. That syntax doesn't seem to work in Perl?

I just tried to use a decode and turn it into a hash, but it seems to not like my syntax accessing it.

Like, it should decode into this, right? :

```
(
  'location' => ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
  'quantity' => [1, 3, 5],
  'userstamp'=> ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Briggs']
)
```

Then I thought I could access it like `$object{"location"}{0}`, but it is throwing a syntax error.

I'm sort of at a loss on how I should tackle this data retrieval process. I feel like I'm missing one crucial step or piece of info here.

I did a `print STDERR Dumper \%object` and it just gave me:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'HASH(0x556e7a37c3e0)' => undef
        };
```

Comment: Tip: `'location' =>` can be written as `location =>` since `=>` autoquotes identifiers on its left-hand side. (In fact, that's the only difference between `=>` and `,`.)

Comment: Hey, I was also editing it as you were haha. I didn't want any more confusion either. The answer provided really isn't an answer to my issue (although very helpful). I also added more of my own research into the issue as well.

Comment: "_I was also editing it as you were_"  -- oh, ok,  That `[...]` instead of `{...}` _was_ a problem.  The other problem is the attempt to dereference an array-reference using `{...}` -- that is syntax for a hash reference. For an array reference you want `->[0]` with square brackets, which may often be shortened to `...[0]` (not `{0}` with curlies).

Comment: So, `$object->{"location"}->[0]`, what may be simplified to `$object->{location}[0]` (and no further, need that first "arrow" `->`)

Comment: Can you show how you read a JSON file/data into a Perl program?

Comment: Sure, so according to the JSON module documentation, `$perl_scalar = decode_json $json_text`. 
https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#decode_json

Comment: OK, but that returns a hash _reference_ -- that `$perl_scalar` you assign it to contains a hash reference. What is then that hash that I see used (`%object`) in the question?  (I've removed some of those early comments of mine.)

Comment: Having `use strict;` in your programs would help a lot. It would force you to be far more deliberate and careful with your variables. One example -- here you couldn't assign a decoded json string to a scalar (correctly) but use a hash (incorrectly). Since you wouldn't have both variables (scalar and hash) declared  the undeclared one would be flagged. Then, when you'd try to conflate them to a single variable you'd realize that something's off and then you'd probably realize that it need be hash _reference_, not a hash.  So always have `use strict;` :)

Comment: use strict is already on :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question after days of pulling hair out, and not understanding Perl's handling of JSON, I have figured this out.

Perl by default works with references, and this the `decode_json()` function in the JSON Module was working, but passing back a reference. What I didn't know was how to dereference that decoded JSON into a usable hash.

Maybe my question was poorly formed. Maybe people just didn't know. However, for any future confused Perl user, I hope this helps.

```
my $myHashRefDecoded = decode_json($myJSONstring);
my %myHashDecoded = %$myHashRefDecoded;
```

This basically answered my question here: [Decoding Hash from JSON-String in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759097/decoding-hash-from-json-string-in-perl)

I was missing one crucial step after decoding, and now have a usable hash (associative multidimensional array) that can be used anywhere I need it.